# CSS doesn't load on Heroku, when I enabled an asset server (AWS) to serve images? Using Rails4, Carrierwave, Heroku, Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I have an app on Heroku and finally managed to save uploaded images (using Carrierwave) to Amazon S3, they show in my bucket and all is fine, but I had to add this to my production.rb:

```
# Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
config.action_controller.asset_host = "https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket"
```

However now there is something wrong with my asset pipeline. It looks for the CSS and Javascript from the config.action_controller.asset_host and I would like to load them normally on Heroku. I tried adding this, but it didn't work:

```
# Precompile additional assets. application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
  config.assets.precompile += %w( 'custom.css.scss' )
```

I also tried to run RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile

On localhost everything works fine, but when I push to heroku, then the CSS brakes.

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sample code taken directly (but slightly modified) from the [documentation of `asset_host`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.2/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html)

```
ActionController::Base.asset_host = Proc.new { |source|
  if source.ends_with?('.css')
    "http://myapp.herokuapp.com"
  else
    "http://assets.example.com"
  end
}

image_tag("rails.png")
# => <img alt="Rails" src="http://assets.example.com/assets/rails.png" />
stylesheet_link_tag("application")
# => <link href="http://myapp.herokuapp.com/assets/application.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Thanks! I put this to my production.rb and of course changed the links, but still doesn't work. Maybe there is something with the asset pipeline, that it doesn't upload my custom.css to Heroku?

Comment: try loading the url you find in the head tag and see if you can get it.  If you can't see the differences in the url and change the strings you pass.  Also make sure that you are serving assets in production.

Comment: Now everything works! :) I had to put the ActionController::Base.asset_host code in the carrierwave.rb and not in the production.rb, as I first did. Many thanks for your help!